# What is the Chrome Automation Extension in Selenium, Python?

Tags: python, selenium

I have recently started using Selenium again and noticed that there is now an extension called Chrome Automation Extension, from my understanding this helps with automating chrome, but I am very unsure what it actually does. I have two questions:

1. Does this send any information to websites I visit, e.g. browsing history, that I am using Selenium, what other extensions I am using etc.?
2. Can I remove it without it detrimentally affecting the performance of Selenium?

Comment: I hope it is Chrome Browser Automation extension. You can find some information here [CBA](http://chrome-automation.com/tutorials)

Comment: It is only called Chrome Automation Extension, however it only shows up when i use Selenium?

Comment: oh ok. Could you share some more information like image

Comment: This is what the icon looks like https://imgur.com/a/EjVR1z2